# on protractor --elementExplorer command browser terminates with error

Tags: node.js, angularjs, debugging, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to use element explorer so that I can interactively fire protractor command.

However after firing below command the browser launches and then terminates suddenly

command:- `protractor --elementExplorer`

The error message is as below:-

```
protractor --elementExplorer
[09:37:47] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[09:37:48] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.56.1:57128/wd/hub
[09:37:52] E/launcher - TypeError: browser.enterRepl is not a function
```

Is this feature not supported after async / await has come into picture and the control flow disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what this parameter is and what the function does, but [this protractor API page](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.enterRepl) suggests to use `browser.explore()` instead

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. However I tried adding the await browser.explore(); statement in my spec file. However the test fails with error stating as =>>> Failed: browser.explore is not a function. I was going through the code for this function in the code. It says as below 
  /**
   * Beta (unstable) explore function for entering the repl loop from
   * any point in the control flow. Use browser.explore() in your test.
   * Does not require changes to the command line (no need to add 'debug').                                  Am i making some mistake?